# assigning a new object and keeping the reference?

Tags: javascript, typed-arrays

consider this:

```
var o = { a: 1 }

read(o);
write(o);
read(o);

function read(x) {
  console.log(x);
}

function write(x) {
  x = { a: 2 };
}
```

Obviously the result is:

```
Object { a=1 }
Object { a=1 }
```

The write Function destroys the reference to the object by assigning a new object. Is there a way to do both - assigning a new object and keeping the reference? I need this to concat two Float32Arrays. As far as I could find out there is no possibility to concat them without creating a new Float32Array. Or is there one? They are supposed to be fast, but to me it looks rather slow if I always have to create a new one if I want to combine two fragments. But maybe this is another question.

Comment: That's not the result you'd get from this code.

Comment: JS is a pass-by-value language. Your `write` function won't work as you expected.

Comment: sorry, the two was a typo!!

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
function overwrite(x,y){
  for (var prop in y) {
    if( y.hasOwnProperty(prop) ) {
      x[prop] = y[prop];
    }
  }
}
```

Example: `overwrite(o,{a:2});`

Answer (score 0):

(ES6) To insert values from one array into a typeed array, starting at an arbitrary index, try the [typed array set() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/set).

```
// dest ... destination typed array
// scr ... array like object with elements to add
dest.set(src, dest.length);  // append src elements to dest typed array
```

Comment: "All values from the source array are copied into the target array, unless the length of the source array plus the offset exceeds the length of the target array". So the length of the Float32Array cannot be changed after creation.